# How to compute the conditional probability in R?

Tags: r, probability

Let's suppose I have these two vectors:

```
x = rnorm(20)
y = rnorm(20)
```

I want to compute the probability that `y > 0` given that `x > 0`. 
In other words, I want the frequency that my `y > 0` when `x > 0`.
Can anyone show me how to code this in R?

Comment: Since y is sampled independently of x, P(y > 0 | x > 0) = P(y > 0). Given than y is normal with mean 0 and variance 1, P(y > 0) = 1/2. No code is necessary.

Comment: OF COURSE WAS JUST AN EXAMPLE, I HAVE ACTUAL DATA OBVIOUSLY.

Comment: AND BY THE WAY THEY ARE NOT SAMPLED INDEPENDENTLY, THE PSEUDO RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR SAMPLE NORMAL NUMBER AS UNCORRELATED AS POSSIBLE, BUT OF COURSE ARE NOT INDEPENDENT

Comment: (0) There's no need to shout. (1) It's not obvious that you have actual data -- you didn't mention it before. You might want to reread your question and try to imagine that you are someone else, trying to understand what you want. (2) I dunno. These days random number generators are constructed to be very, very close to uncorrelated and independent. If you can detect some dependence, that indicates a bug in the generator and I'm sure the authors would be interested to hear about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the results reproducible,  I will  use `set.seed`

```
set.seed(42)
x = rnorm(20)
y = rnorm(20)
```

You can just subset the data to select the ones where x>0  and then count what proportion of those have y>0

```
PosX = which(x>0)
sum(y[PosX] > 0)/length(PosX)
[1] 0.6
```

Comment: Or `mean(y[x>0]>0)`